# How to convert a list of strings to multiple url links?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I currently am pulling a list of url's from a view using  Entity Framework 5 and MVC 5. I need to populate a list of url's in the view from this database view. Currently I have:

**Repository:**

```
public class LinkRepository
{
    private readonly LinkLibrary _entities = new LinkLibrary ();


    public LinkRepository()
    {
        _entities = new LinkLibrary ();
    }


    public List<LinkModels> RetrieveStateLink(string year)
    {
        return
            _entities.vw_URLLibrary.Where(s => s.YEAR.Equals(year) && s.URL_TYPE.Equals("United States")).Select(m => new LinkModels()
            {
                UrlLink = m.LinkLocation
            }).ToList();
    }
}
```

**Model**

```
public class LinkModels
{
    public string LinkYear { get; set; }
    public string LinkState { get; set; }
    public string UrlLink { get; set; }
    public string LinkType { get; set; }
    public List<string> ListOfUrls{ get; set; }
}
```

**Controller**

```
public ActionResult GetStateLinks()
    {
        var stateLink = new List<string>();
        var model = rr.RetrieveStateLinks("2014").Select(m=> m.UrlLink).ToList();
        foreach (var s in model)
        {
            stateLink.Add(s);
        }

        var rm = new LinkModels();
        rm.ListOfUrls = stateLink;

        return View(rm.ListOfUrls);
    }
```

**View**

```
<ol>
    @foreach (var item in Model.ListOfUrls)
    {
        <li>
            @Html.ActionLink("state", "GetStateLinks", new { mystring = item })
        </li>
    }
</ol>
```

I am unsure how to pass this into the view to where it will display:

Alabama.aspx
Georgia.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should simply write

```
<ol>
    @foreach (var item in Model.ListOfUrls)
    {
        <li>
            <a href="@item">GetStateLinks</a>
        </li>
    }
</ol>
```

There's no need to use `Html.ActionLink`, as it's purpose is to link directly to an MVC controller action, not a URL.

Comment: I just tried this, now I am getting this error:

The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.String]', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'LinkLibraryProject.Models.LinkModels'.

Comment: @masta_coda Oh, I missed that. You need to change `return View(rm.ListOfUrls)` into simply `return View(rm)`

Comment: @masta_coda No worries, mate :)

Comment: is there any way to pull the display name? Like instead of GetStateLinks it can pull the 'LinkState' in my model?

Comment: @masta_coda Sure, you'd just write `@Model.LinkState` - however that state is for the entire model, not for each URL

Comment: How could I pull it for each state? Thanks for your help!

Comment: @masta_coda You would really need to change how you're storing the data in your database, as well as your view model. Instead of having `List<string>` you'd have something like `List<Url>`, which contains the information about the URL (state, actually link, etc).